# Де наголос у слові "шкода"?

Tags: омоніми

Іменник "шкода" із наголосом на першому складі, прислівник матиме наголос на другому складі. За змістом вони ідентичні чи різні? Наприклад, як висловитися із приводу сумної події: "Шкода, що так сталося" - де тут наголос і який сенс матиме речення залежно від того, іменник чи прислівник буде у першій частині речення?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте [дивитися](http://sum.in.ua/s/shkoda) конкретно на визначення цих слів:

1. Шкода з наголосом на перший склад:

> Матеріальні втрати; збитки. Де незгода, там часто шкода (Українські народні прислів'я та приказки, 1963, 157); Де п'ють, то там і ллють,
>   без шкоди не бува (Гулак-Артемовський, Байки.., 1958, 61); Там чи
>   купити що, чи продати, — зроду-віку не послухає; хоч шкода з того
>   видима буде, вона свого докаже (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 5);

2. Шкода з наголосом на другий склад

> 1. кого, чого, без додатка і з інфін. Про жалість (у 1 знач.), співчуття до кого-, чого-небудь; жаль. Кров не вода, розливати шкода (Українські народні прислів'я та приказки, 1963, 204);
> 2. чого, без додатка, з інфін. і з спол. що. Про почуття **прикрості** з приводу втрати чого-небудь. Шкода мені й досі тієї пасіки, що я її спродав! (Марко Вовчок, VI, 1956, 218);
> 3. чого і з інфін. Про небажання витрачати, віддавати що-небудь, позбуватися чогось. Зачали панотці хвалитися, що нічого не читають. —
>      І ця газета нездала, і та нездала, шкода часу! (Лесь Мартович, Тв.,
>      1954, 215);

Спробуємо підставити у ваше речення "шкоду" з наголосом на перший склад, тільки замінимо це слово на "матеріальні збитки":

- Матеріальні збитки, що так сталося.

Це речення вочевидь не має сенсу.

Більше підходить другий варіант тлумачення слова "шкода" з наголосом на другий склад. Вам **прикро**, що так сталося, отже, шкод**а**, що так сталося.